# Pre-launch report details throw stability issue: android.apps.wellbeing

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

The email I receive says

A new pre-launch report is ready
You can now view your pre-launch report results for app version 30015. No issues were found.

But if I open up the View report, I get Errors found. Fix before releasing to production. 1 unique issue.  Which is Application Not Responding android.apps.wellbeing App.

the exact error I receive is,

ANR in com.google.android.apps.wellbeing;PID: 5865;Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED flg=0x1200810 cmp=com.google.android.apps.wellbeing/.winddown.impl.WindDownRefreshStateBroadcastReceiver_Receiver };

Is there anything I can do to stop this error?  It seems I crash the wellbeing App only on Pixel 2 (virtual) Android 13 (SDK 33) in my Pre-launch report.  My concern is even though it is not my App, how does this effect my release to Production?

Comment: Did you manage to either fix this or release without it being a concern? I have the exact same issue

Comment: Turns out the Well Being App is problematic.  On one build it will cause issues and the next build it will not show any issues.  I deployed to production with no issues.  Not sure why I got a downvote for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is the Wellbeing App that is causing the issue you can ignore it.  I had it show the warning on one build and not show up two builds latter including Production builds